How to Dynamically Load and Apply Fonts from Server (self-hosted) in a React App with MUI
I'm working on a React application using the MUI library and facing an issue with dynamically setting the font-family. The goal is to allow users to select a font from a configurator, where fonts are hosted on a remote server (not within the project files due to specific requirements).
Here's my current approach to building the theme and fetching the font::
  const buildTheme = () => {
    /**
     * Fetch data and store it in the state.
     *
     * src: url to the font stored on the server (EX: https://storage.com/documents/fonts/examplefont.ttf).
     * cssValue: font-family value
     */
    const {
      fontData: { src, name },
    } = state;

    return createTheme(getBaseTheme(cssValue), {
      components: {
        MuiCssBaseline: {
          styleOverrides: {
            '@font-face': {
              fontFamily: name,
              src: `url(${src})`,
            },
          },
        },
      },
    });
  };

// ThemeProvider setup
<ThemeProvider theme={buildTheme()}>
  <CssBaseline />
  {globalStyles}
  {children}
</ThemeProvider>

With this setup, the @font-face rule is correctly added to the styleOverrides, and the app's Typography settings seem to be configured correctly. However, the font is not being rendered in the UI.
I also tried an alternative approach using a useEffect hook to append a  element to the document head, but this didn't work either:
  useEffect(() => {
    const link = document.createElement('link');
    link.href = state.systemFontFamily.src;
    link.rel = 'stylesheet';
    document.head.appendChild(link);
  }, [state.fontData]);

(Don't throw tomatoes at me for this call, I was as clueless as a cat in a salsa class about what the fuss was at that after couple of hours with no proggress on that).
Despite these efforts, none of the self-hosted fonts are rendering. There are no CORS errors or other relevant messages in the console.
What am I missing here, and how can I successfully load and apply fonts from a server in my MUI-based React app?

Answer:
Mui has changed the way we should handle any @font-face overrides. Propper (updated) way to do it:
components: {
        MuiCssBaseline: {
          styleOverrides: `
               @font-face {
                font-family: ${name}; // "Fira Code"
                src:  url(${src}); // https://font-host.github.io/fira-code.woff2
              }
             `,
        },
      },

So, no need to use the  or whatsoever hehe 
PS:
Feel free to expand this, or criticize this solution, will gladly improve.
